# How could i make my site update or delete the user?

Tags: php

I can't get the users name to get updated or to deleted the user. Whatever i try doesn't work. When i click on the update button it just goes to the index page and nothing happens and the same happens when i click on the delete button too.

this is the codes i have on my server.php page:

```
<?php
session_start();

// initializing variables
$idmedlemmer = "";
$brukernavn = "";
$email    = "";
$fornavn  = "";
$etternavn = "";
$errors = array(); 

// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mymusic");

// Update User
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form
  $brukernavn = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['brukernavn']);

  // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...
  // by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array
  if (empty($brukernavn)) { array_push($errors, "Feltet kan ikke være tomt"); }

  // first check the database to make sure 
  // a user does not already exist with the same username and/or email
  $user_check_query = "SELECT brukernavn FROM medlemmer LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  if ($user) { // if user exists
    if ($user['brukernavn'] === $brukernavn) {
      array_push($errors, "Brukernavn eksisterer allerede");
    }
  }

  // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
  if (count($errors) == 0) {

    mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE medlemmer SET brukernavn='$brukernavn' WHERE idmedlemmer=$idmedlemmer");
    $_SESSION['message'] = "Brukernavnet har blitt oppdatert";
    header('location: index.php');
  }
}

// ... 
// ... 

// Delete User
if (isset($_GET['brukernavn']))
if (isset($_GET['slett'])) {

    $query = sprintf("DELETE FROM medlemmer WHERE idmedlemmer='%s'");
    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    $_SESSION['brukernavn'] = $brukernavn;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "Bruker har blitt slettet";
    header('location: Login.php');
  }

?>
```

And this is what i have on my update page:

```
<?php include('server.php')?>
<?php 
  if (isset($_GET['update'])) {
    $brukernavn = $_GET['update'];
    $record = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM medlemmer WHERE brukernavn=$brukernavn");

    if (count($record) == 1 ) {
      $n = mysqli_fetch_array($record);
      $name = $n['brukernavn'];
    }
  }
?>
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Edit Data</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stilark.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>    
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">
        <table border="0">
            <tr> 
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="brukernavn" value="<?php echo ($_SESSION['brukernavn']); ?>"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="idmedlemmer" value="<?php echo $idmedlemmer;?>"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="update"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

and this is what i have on my delete page:

```
<?php include('Server.php')?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stilark.css">

<head>    
    <title>Slett Bruker</title>
</head>

<body>
    <a href="index.php">Tilbake</a>
    <br/><br/>

    <form name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="idmedlemmer" value="<?php echo $_GET['idmedlemmer'];?>"></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="slett" value="slett"></td>
                <a href="server.php?del=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" class="del_btn">Delete</a>
            </tr>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to check on youtube videoes and read many articles but i just cant seem to get anywhere so i am totaly stuck and appreciate all the help i can get. Hope that you can help me

Comment: This variable is empty: $idmedlemmer in server.php.
You initialize it with '' value but you never set anything else to it so your query is performed but it does not do anything because you do not have id = '';

Probably you need to get it via POST request.
$idmedlemmer = trim($_POST['idmedlemmer'] ); before you perform UPDATE query.

Comment: im sorry for a late response, i have tried the things you told me, but i didn't quite get where i needed to use the "$idmedlemmer = trim($_POST['idmedlemmer'] );" and if i needed to set anything else to the query.